# Is there is a way to overlay one rotated PDF document over another one?

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, ghostscript

I have SVG documents which I convert to PDF via ghostscript in the end of my workflow. Now I have to add a new feature.
I need to replace some element in the SVG with PDF content. It's not 
just overlay, it could be rotated and scaled proportionally, here is an image for example:

[image: 1]"example"

My question is are there any way to do it with ghostscript?

At the moment I just insert it as rasterized image by SVG image elements but I'll need it to be vector for printing.

NOTE: I'll need to take only first page from the inserted PDF.

I know there are a pdftk which can overlay one PDF file over another, but I can't scale and rotate overlayed PDF document with it.

Comment: You can't be creating PDF directly from SVG using Ghostscript, as Ghostscript doesn't read SVG files. It therefore depends on what it is you are actually sending to Ghostscript to create hte PDF file. It is 'possible' that you may be able to draw the PDF content on top of existing content. However, you can't 'replace' anything using the pdfwrite device. If there are two items in the same location on the page, then both will be in the final PDF file. You really need to come up with an example and a Ghostscript command line of what you are currently doing.

Comment: Kens, thanks for replying. Actually I realized that I didn't explain it correctly. I actually first convert SVG to PDF with Inkscape and then do some postprocessing (RGB -> CMYK conversion, etc.) by Ghostscript. So my question is how actually place one PDF over another one but upper PDF should be rotated by some angles and should have its coordinates on the target page.

Comment: You can't do it (simply) from the command line, you would need to write a PostScript program. You'd need to opent he first PDF fiel, draw the page content, then close that PDF file, alter the CTM, open the secodn PDF file, draw the page content, close that and complete. In the current incarnation of Ghostscript's PDF itnerpreter you would also have to close the input from the first PDF before starting the second PDF, I think you might aso lose some metadata (eg Links, outlines etc) I don't know if either of those is a problem for you.

Comment: I can have a go at your problem, but I'll need some example files (and angles etc) to work from.

Comment: Thanks, KenS! I've prepared two files. https://krokbase.in.ua/pdfs/target.pdf and https://krokbase.in.ua/pdfs/source.pdf I think the simplest example will be enough for me, I just don't understand how I can iterate over objects, transform them and then place transformed objects to other canvas....

Comment: Its getting late for me, sorry, I'll pick these up tomorrow and give it a try. What angle/scale do you need applied to the source PDF?  (I'm assuming you want source.pdf placed over target.pdf)

Comment: I appreciate your help! actually it doesn't metter, you can make it like 5 times smaller and rotate to some angle. I'll take this data from my software (which is vector editor software) and write a script which takes these parameters.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198952/discussion-between-andrew-zolotukhin-and-kens).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid that, due to recent changes in the Ghostscript PDF interpreter to address security vulnerabilities, this code will only work with versions up to 9.26. In future the PDF interpreter will be altered and there will be better ways to achieve this, but I'm afraid that's a long-term goal. For now, to use this code, you'll need to stick with an older version.

The PostScript program which does this is as follows:

```
%!PS

%%
%% This code is copied from pdf_main.ps, pdfshowpage_finish
%% sadly that routine always calls showpage, and we want that
%% to be under our control, so we have to duplicate the code
%% here. Not only that but it uses GS extensions which aren't
%% available outside of startup, so some things it simply can't
%% replicate. As a result some of the error handling is less
%% good.
%%
%% I plan to extend the PDF interpreter with two new
%% routines, pdfnoshowpage_finish and then have both
%% that and pdfshowpage_finish call pdfoptionalshowpage_finish
%% which will take a boolean determining whether to actually
%% call the showpage. At that time we'll alter this code.
%%
/draw_page_content {    % <pagedict> pdfshowpage_finish -
   save /PDFSave exch store
   /PDFdictstackcount countdictstack store
   /PDFexecstackcount count 2 sub store
   (before exec) VMDEBUG

   % set up color space substitution (this must be inside the page save)
   pdfshowpage_setcspacesub

        % Display the actual page contents.
   8 dict begin
   /BXlevel 0 def
   /BMClevel 0 def
   /OFFlevels 0 dict def
   /BGDefault currentblackgeneration def
   /UCRDefault currentundercolorremoval def
        %****** DOESN'T HANDLE COLOR TRANSFER YET ******
   /TRDefault currenttransfer def
  matrix currentmatrix 
  2 dict
  dictbeginpage setmatrix
  /DefaultQstate qstate store

  count 1 sub /pdfemptycount exch store
        % If the page uses any transparency features, show it within
        % a transparency group.
  dup pageusestransparency dup /PDFusingtransparency exch def {
    % Show the page within a PDF 1.4 device filter.
    0 .pushpdf14devicefilter {
      /DefaultQstate qstate store       % device has changed -- reset DefaultQstate
      % If the page has a Group, enclose contents in transparency group.
      % (Adobe Tech Note 5407, sec 9.2)
      dup /Group knownoget {
        1 index /CropBox pget {
          /CropBox exch
        } {
          1 index get_media_box pop /MediaBox exch
        } ifelse
        oforce_elems normrect_elems fix_empty_rect_elems 4 array astore .beginformgroup 
        showpagecontents
        .endtransparencygroup
      } {
        showpagecontents
      } ifelse
    } stopped {
      % abort the transparency device 
      .abortpdf14devicefilter
      /DefaultQstate qstate store   % device has changed -- reset DefaultQstate
      stop
    } if .poppdf14devicefilter
    /DefaultQstate qstate store % device has changed -- reset DefaultQstate
  } {
    showpagecontents
  } ifelse
  .free_page_resources
  % todo: mixing drawing ops outside the device filter could cause
  % problems, for example with the pnga device.

  end           % scratch dict
  % Some PDF files don't have matching q/Q (gsave/grestore) so we need
  % to clean up any left over dicts from the dictstack

  PDFdictstackcount //false
  { countdictstack 2 index le { exit } if
    currentdict /n known not or
    end
  } loop 

  pop
  count PDFexecstackcount sub { pop } repeat
  Repaired      % pass Repaired state around the restore
  PDFSave restore
  currentglobal pdfdict gcheck .setglobal
  .setglobal
  /Repaired exch def
} def

% And now, draw the page from the first PDF file
(d:/temp/SO/target.pdf) (r) file runpdfbegin
save
1 pdfgetpage
dup /Page exch store                                         draw_page_content
restore                                      
runpdfend

% and then the page from the second PDF file
(d:/temp/SO/source.pdf) (r) file runpdfbegin
save
1 pdfgetpage
dup /Page exch store                                        

% Before drawing the second page, adjust the CTM so
% that the bottom left corner of the page is co-incident
% with the bottom left of the area we want to draw the
% page in
75 575 translate

% adjust the size of the output
0.11 0.11 scale

% and rotate it
-46 rotate

draw_page_content
restore                                      
runpdfend

showpage
```

Save that in a file, lets call it test.ps, and adjust the paths in the PostScript program suitably. Then run Ghostscript with: `gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=out.pdf test.ps` and you'll get a PDF file something like what I think you want. Obviously you'll also need to change the numbers for translate/scale/rotate.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it tomorrow and let you know. Thank you again!

Comment: KenS, one small question. Are there a way to rotate source document over it's center point, not over the left bottom corner?

Comment: Ok, I'll write a code that will recalculate correct values, thanks!

Comment: Hi KenS, sorry for bothering you once again. But I found two issues with this code and don't know how to fix it. All these PS statements looks like a magic for me :) So, the first issue is that sometimes when I paste document to canvas it deletes content of the initial document. I prepared files to reproduce http://www.krokbase.in.ua/pdfs/demo.tar.gz. This is your code, I just tried with other files. I'm running it on GS 9.22 on Ubuntu by doing: gs  -q -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=out.pdf paste.ps

Comment: Another issue is that when I paste PDF it changes dimentions of initial PDF file...So if I have 750x750 pdf and insert there another PDF with size of the page = A4. Resulting PDF file will have A4 page size.

Comment: I'm on vacation and can't give you a full answer for another 10 days. However, this program specifically does not use the dimensions of the PDF (either of them) to set the output dimensions, you will have to do that yourself. See -sPAPERSIZE or -dDEVICEWIDTHPOINTS and -DDEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS. A4 is probably the default for your build of Ghostscript.

Comment: Ok! Thanks! Have a great vacation!

Comment: Hi KenS, I noticed that it is happening not for all files, and sometimes it's working fine even with files I've sent you but when I remove an image from the file. I'm just wondering if you have an idea why it's happening?

Comment: Offhand, no. It could be that you are altering one of the other Box parameters, but I'd need to see the file. Ah, it looks like you did, sorry I missed that, what with being away. Let me look at the demo you pointed at earlier

Comment: OK the reason is that the file you are placing on top has transparency, but the underneath file doesn't. Basically you can't do that, its kind of technical tro try and explain why, but its to do with initialising hte transparency compositing buffers. In order for that to work they have to be set up **before** the first file runs. So if the first file uses transparency on the page then it works, if neither file uses transparency then it works, if the first file doesn't, btu the second file does, then it doesn't work. Lots of tools insert 'pointless' transparency (ie it does nothing).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I I'll search for such tools and will keep my tests.

Comment: KenS, I got back to this task and unfortunately didn't find a tool which can add transparency to PDF file, would you mind if I ask you for some help (links or names of software). Adding transparent rectangle to the first PDF didn't help to fix that issue. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I can't usefully give you any files. I also don't know specifically of any software which will ad transparency, but the Cairo graphics library produces PDF files which pretty much always contain transparency, even when its not actually required. I think you could use Ghostscript's support for transparency pdfmarks to add transparency to a file, you would have to figure it out from the pdfmark reference though.

Comment: Hi Kens, thanks a lot for your solution, it helped to resolve my problem. One more quick question: are there is a way to skew inserted document? I found that there is away to set a transformation matrix by doing something like: **[1 0 1 1 0 0] concat** it should skew context before calling of draw_page_content. And after that I should return context to identity somehow. I tried to do **[1 0 -1 1 0 0] concat** but it didn't help...

Comment: By "identity" I mean initial context (before pdf insert).

Comment: The easy way to deal with this is to do a gsave (save the graphics state) before the transformation, and then grestore (restore the graphics state) after you're done with it. The CTM is part of the graphics state and so will obey gsave/grestore.

Comment: Thanks! And the final question, it's not that important for me, but just wondering why that's happening. If inserted document contains text (with embeded fonts) and angle is more than 90. Ghostscript changes an orientation of resulting document (whole resulting document will be 90 degrees rotated).  I don't really sure that texts or fonts causes the issue but I couldn't reproduce that on documents containing only images and vector graphics.

Comment: Because of AutoRotatePages. Its a heuristic which attempts to rotate pages so that the majority of the text is 'upright' and runs left to right. It is documented and you can set it to /None to stop it. Obviously it only works with actual text, not images or linwork which 'looks lke' text.

Comment: Yay! That worked, thanks. But I have a one more "last" question :) Are there any way to clip posted PDF? Let me explain what I mean. Before post PDF I crop it by GS command, something like:        gs -o $CROPPED_PAGE -q -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dFirstPage=$pageIndex -dLastPage=$pageIndex -dDEVICEWIDTHPOINTS=$cropWidth -dDEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS=$cropHeight -dFIXEDMEDIA -c "<</PageOffset [${cropX} ${cropY}]>> setpagedevice" -f ${FILES[$i]}. And only then I post it to the canvas. It leads to that whole file(even cropped part) being rendered in bounding rectangle of the rotated PDF.

Comment: I tried to clip it by rectangle doing (just before draw_page_content) something like: 0 0 moveto 0 100 lineto 100 100 lineto 100 0 lineto 0 0 lineto clip. But it seems like draw_page_content doesn't pay attention to current device clip.

Comment: It can't **not** 'pay attention' to the clip, since that's performed by the graphics library, not the interpreter. PageOffset does not alter the clip rectangle, it simply repositions the content on the current media. Obviously portions which lie off the media will be 'clipped', because they are in a position where they are not rendered. If you want to clip properly then yes, you will need to set a clip rectanlge. Its possible the code above ends up resetting the clip though, I have not checked since it was not part of the original question.

Comment: How I can check that? When I place some PDF file of size 300x300pts with scale 1,1 and angle 0 in point 0,0 and a execute a: **newpath 0 0 moveto 0 50 lineto 50 50 lineto 50 0 lineto closepath clip draw_page_content**. It draws it 300x300 instead of clip it by 50x50 rectangle. I'm not sure if that's I'm doing something wrong or this code just don't allows to clip pasted rectangle.

Comment: PDF files don't have a media size in pixels, its in PDF units, 1/72 inch. If you want to check the action of the draw_page_content function then you'll need to be able to read PostScript because that's the language its coded in. You'll also need to refer extensively to the Ghostscript PDF interpreter (which is also currently written in PostScript) because the code above uses a lot of the functions defined for use by the PDF interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting here a solution which support clipping of pasted PDF file in case if somebody will need it in future. I've added additional parameters to draw_page_content to support that. I appeared that "dict beginpage setmatrix" command somehow overrides clipping path and it should be set only after that command. I'm not an expert in PostScript, but at least this solution is working. Thanks again KenS for your help.

```
%!PS

%%
%% This code is copied from pdf_main.ps, pdfshowpage_finish
%% sadly that routine always calls showpage, and we want that
%% to be under our control, so we have to duplicate the code
%% here. Not only that but it uses GS extensions which aren't
%% available outside of startup, so some things it simply can't
%% replicate. As a result some of the error handling is less
%% good.
%%
%% I plan to extend the PDF interpreter with two new
%% routines, pdfnoshowpage_finish and then have both
%% that and pdfshowpage_finish call pdfoptionalshowpage_finish
%% which will take a boolean determining whether to actually
%% call the showpage. At that time we'll alter this code.
%%
/draw_page_content {    % <pagedict> pdfshowpage_finish -
   /clipx exch def /clipy exch def /clip_width exch def /clip_height exch def /should_clip exch def
   save /PDFSave exch store
   /PDFdictstackcount countdictstack store
   /PDFexecstackcount count 2 sub store
   (before exec) VMDEBUG

   % set up color space substitution (this must be inside the page save)
   pdfshowpage_setcspacesub

        % Display the actual page contents.
   8 dict begin
   /BXlevel 0 def
   /BMClevel 0 def
   /OFFlevels 0 dict def
   /BGDefault currentblackgeneration def
   /UCRDefault currentundercolorremoval def
        %****** DOESN'T HANDLE COLOR TRANSFER YET ******
   /TRDefault currenttransfer def
  matrix currentmatrix 
  2 dict
  dictbeginpage setmatrix

  % set clipping here
  should_clip 0 gt
  {
    newpath clipx clipy moveto clipx clipy clip_height add lineto clipx clip_width add clipy clip_height add lineto clipx clip_width add clipy lineto closepath clip
  }
  {
  }
  ifelse

  /DefaultQstate qstate store

  count 1 sub /pdfemptycount exch store
        % If the page uses any transparency features, show it within
        % a transparency group.
  dup pageusestransparency dup /PDFusingtransparency exch def {
    % Show the page within a PDF 1.4 device filter.
    0 .pushpdf14devicefilter {
      /DefaultQstate qstate store       % device has changed -- reset DefaultQstate
      % If the page has a Group, enclose contents in transparency group.
      % (Adobe Tech Note 5407, sec 9.2)
      dup /Group knownoget {
        1 index /CropBox pget {
          /CropBox exch
        } {
          1 index get_media_box pop /MediaBox exch
        } ifelse
        oforce_elems normrect_elems fix_empty_rect_elems 4 array astore .beginformgroup 
        showpagecontents
        .endtransparencygroup
      } {
        showpagecontents
      } ifelse
    } stopped {
      % abort the transparency device 
      .abortpdf14devicefilter
      /DefaultQstate qstate store   % device has changed -- reset DefaultQstate
      stop
    } if .poppdf14devicefilter
    /DefaultQstate qstate store % device has changed -- reset DefaultQstate
  } {
    showpagecontents
  } ifelse
  .free_page_resources
  % todo: mixing drawing ops outside the device filter could cause
  % problems, for example with the pnga device.

  end           % scratch dict
  % Some PDF files don't have matching q/Q (gsave/grestore) so we need
  % to clean up any left over dicts from the dictstack

  PDFdictstackcount //false
  { countdictstack 2 index le { exit } if
    currentdict /n known not or
    end
  } loop 

  pop
  count PDFexecstackcount sub { pop } repeat
  Repaired      % pass Repaired state around the restore
  PDFSave restore
  currentglobal pdfdict gcheck .setglobal
  .setglobal
  /Repaired exch def
} bind def

% And now, draw the page from teh first PDF file
(/opt/files/main.pdf) (r) file runpdfbegin
save
1 pdfgetpage
dup /Page exch store 0 1125 1125 0 0 draw_page_content
restore                                      
runpdfend

gsave

% and then the page from the next PDF file
(/opt/files/placement1.pdf) (r) file runpdfbegin
save
1 pdfgetpage
dup /Page exch store                                        

% Before drawing the second page, adjust the CTM so
% that the bottom left corner of the page is co-incident
% with the bottom left of the area we want to draw the
% page in
120 120 translate

% and rotate it
25 rotate

% adjust the size of the output
0.7 0.7 scale

%let's skew file
[1 0 1.3 1 0 0] concat

% draw file and clip it
1 100 100 0 0 draw_page_content

restore                                      
runpdfend
grestore

showpage
```